# SSRS 2008 - Line Chart - How to shade an area of the chart?

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have a line chart. The line represents the average thickness of material we apply to glass. The Y Axis represents the thickness and the X axis represents time. Say the range of values on the Y axis is between 1 and 10. The average thickness is say typically between 3 and 5, but must fall within a range, on the low side of 2 and on the high side of 7. I would like to shade the area of the graph between 2 and 7, to indicate the acceptable range of values. Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a second value series, and change it to the "Range" chart type.  This will allow you to set the high / low Y values discretely.  Rather than choosing a field for these values, just edit the expression and set the static values (in your case, 2 and 7).

From there, edit the series "fill" properties - select Pattern, and find one that works for ya.  There a good set of % fills (5 percent, 10 percent, etc.) midway down the list.

Hope this helps.